# Sending Mail using maingun in Laravel using Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, mailgun

Hello guys i've a problem when try to send email using mailgun

here i follow tutorial from this http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/mailgun-setup-with-laravel-5-exampleexample.html but i found error

like Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
"

I've check all .env , mail.php, service.php, run php artisan config:cache and restart the server but still facing the same problem (i run on my localhost)

Here My .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=christian7andrew@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here my mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'name' => 'PTKP'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','christian7andrew@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','password'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Here is my service.php

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'sandboxf750e42d86cc410fbca6e462c8356bcf.mailgun.org',
    'secret' => 'key-secretdddecd93d0c17c7a1d30secret',
],
```

Route

```
Route::get('kirim/{id}', 'AdminController@kirim');
```

Controller

```
public function kirim(Request $request, $id){
    $keluhan = keluhan::find($id)->toArray();
    //dd($keluhan);
    Mail::send('laporan.email', $keluhan, function($message) use($keluhan) {

        $message->to($keluhan['email_address']);
        $message->subject('Mailgun Testing');
    });

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Any idea ? please kindly help, thank you so much

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139040/discussion-on-question-by-christianus-andre-sending-mail-using-maingun-in-larave).